# Clarify the action of annotationClass

Tags: kotlin

Can you explain the work of "annotationClass  in Kotlin " in your own understanding based on your experience

I searched for annotationClass information on the sites, but I did not understand enough of it.

And thank you for helping me

Comment: Are you talking about this [`annotationClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/annotation-class.html) extension property? What specifically do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

An annotation in Kotlin/Java languages is a way of adding some kind of attribute to a class, member variable, parameter.  This is done with the @ syntax.  Here are two examples:

```
@Async("auditLoggingExecutor")
fun submitAuditLog(log: AuditLogEntry) {
}
```

```
data class QuestionSet(
    val title: String,
    @JsonIgnore
    val questions: List<Question>,
)
```

The `Async` annotation in the first case is a class-level annotation, the second, `JsonIgnore`, is a field-level annotation.

Annotations do nothing for you unless an **Annotation Processor** will read the code and find the annotation and do something.  In the first case, the Annotation belongs to the Spring Framework and it alters the behaviour of calls to this method to be run asynchronously.  In the second case, a JSON serializer (Jackson) will ignore the `questions` field when de/serializing the object into JSON.

The Annotation class itself holds information about the annotation and what meta data may be added.  In the case of the first example, the developer is passing `auditLoggingExecutor` which means something to the Async annotation processor.